# *Dynamic Arrays in Free Pascal

Tags: freepascal

Im having trouble working with dynamic array in Free Pascal. I've an array of TEdit which is dynamically instantiated in run time. For each new item in my array, i increase the Array length by 1. This is all working fine. However, whenever i try to access an specific item in the array (something like MyArray[index], where index would be the position i want to access) it throws an error. It's only allowing me to access (in access i mean retrieving properties such as the TEdit's name/text/etc) the last element of the array.

The error thrown its a "SIGSEGV Exception" and it's thrown out when i try to get the .Text value of the TEdit[x] in the array. It says "GetTextMethod:= (@Self.GetTextBuf);

Any idea what'd be causing this and how to fix it?

**EDITED**

Sorry, I intended to post this last night but didnt have access until now.

Here's how im creating the TEdit's inside the TEdit Array. First I increase the Array Length by 1, then proceed to create the control:

```
setLength(PointsArray, Length(PointsArray) + 1);
setLength(ButtonsArray, Length(ButtonsArray) + 1);
PointsArray[ind]:= TEdit.Create(ScrollBox1);
PointsArray[ind].Name:= 'TPoints'+IntToStr(ind);
PointsArray[ind].NumbersOnly:= true;
PointsArray[ind].Font.Size:= 15;
PointsArray[ind].Width:= 113;
PointsArray[ind].Parent:= ScrollBox1;
PointsArray[ind].SetFocus;
PointsArray[ind].OnKeyDown:=@onKeyDownPoints; 

ButtonsArray[ind]:= TButton.Create(ScrollBox1);
ButtonsArray[ind].Caption:= 'X';
ButtonsArray[ind].Name:= 'BRemove'+IntToStr(ind);
ButtonsArray[ind].Font.Size:= 10;
ButtonsArray[ind].Font.Style:= [fsBold];
ButtonsArray[ind].Width:= 30;
ButtonsArray[ind].Height:= 25;
ButtonsArray[ind].Parent:= ScrollBox1;
ButtonsArray[ind].OnClick:= @onClickRemovePlay;
```

*ind is an integer that is incremented by one everytime a new TEdit control is created.

This is the onClick method that's used to remove the control from the array. Here's where only the last one is accessible while all the others throw SIGSEGV Exception:

```
procedure TFormSellTicket.onClickRemovePlay(Sender: TObject);
var Bbutton  : TButton;
var index   : Integer;
begin
     Bbutton:= Sender as TButton;
     index:= StrToInt(Trim(StringReplace(Bbutton.Name, 'BRemove', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase])));
     begin
          PointsArray[index].Free;
     end;
end;
```

Comment: You have bogus TEdit references in all but the last element of your array. Most probable cause is your code has errors.

Comment: Could you provide an example on how to make this TEdits without having bogus references to it? I'd greatly appreciate it, if it's not too much.

Comment: Use SetLength to increase the length of the array and only assign to the newly allocated element and leave previous references alone. I can't really guess how you're doing it any different now.

Comment: It's much easier to help you if you post code.  In your case, the code where you are allocating, resizing and then accessing the array.

Answer (score 1):

Set nil when destroying the control

```
PointsArray[index].Free;
PointsArray[index] := nil;
```

Take care to check PointsArray[i] <> nil or Assigned(PointsArray[i]) before using it in the rest of your code.

Use lists/collections or generic lists instead of arrays (see FGL unit, TFPGList class) to store objects. The lists allow you simple delete the item after destroying so you won't need to check PointsArray[i] <> nil anymore.